# JOI - Made object key not allowed base on the value of another key

Tags: node.js, typescript, joi, hapi

I have an object like this:

```
type A = {
  type: 'user' | 'technical',
  name: string,
  vat?: string
};
```

I use `joi` to validate the user `request`. I would like a validation that if the `type` is `technical` then the `vat` is `required()` otherwise it's become an `not allowed` field.

For now, this is my validation where if `type` is `user` the field become `optional`:

```
type: Joi.valid('user', 'technical').required(),
name: Joi.string().min(2).max(30).required(),
vat: Joi.string().regex(new RegExp(REGEX_CONSTANTS.VAT_NUMBER)).when('type', { is: 'user', then: Joi.optional() }).required()
```